# Custom Cell from nib leaking

Tags: iphone, memory, uitableview, nib

I have a subclass of UITableViewCell and am trying to use it.  At the moment it does display fine as a test but I get leaking errors to the console...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

    static NSString *CustomCellIdentifier = @"CustomCellIdentifier ";

    LeagueCellNormal *cell = (LeagueCellNormal *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CustomCellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)  
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"LeagueCellNormal" 
                                                     owner:self options:nil];
        cell = (LeagueCellNormal *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];

    }
        return cell;
}
```

Errors:-

```
[Session started at 2009-08-25 06:03:28 +0100.]
2009-08-25 06:03:40.926 MyApp1[1863:5523] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x14b3f70 of class __NSArrayReverseEnumerator autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0x305a2e6f 0x30504682 0x3094a1a6 0x1d2d2 0x3050a79d 0x3050a338 0x94be6155 0x94be6012)
2009-08-25 06:03:40.927 MyApp1[1863:5523] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x1492720 of class NSCFArray autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0x305a2e6f 0x30504682 0x3094a09c 0x3094a225 0x1d2d2 0x3050a79d 0x3050a338 0x94be6155 0x94be6012)
2009-08-25 06:03:40.930 MyApp1[1863:5523] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x14423b0 of class NSCFArray autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0x305a2e6f 0x30504682 0x3094a09c 0x3094a260 0x1d2d2 0x3050a79d 0x3050a338 0x94be6155 0x94be6012)
```

Comment: Solved myself - muppet!

Looks like I called the reloadData from a detached thread.  I then did this on the main thread and all went away!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved myself - muppet! Looks like I called the reloadData from a detached thread. I then did this on the main thread and all went away!